# Accessing and extracting a dictionary set within my dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary within a dictionary like below:

My code looks for todays date and if it exists in dict it should print “found a match at” + dict(name)

```
today = datetime.datetime.now()

if today in dict[name]:
      print "Found a bday for " + str(dict[name])

   #here i need a variable that will hold the email from that name so I can use to somewhere else
```

If I excuse print dict
It looks like this:

```
{'name1': set(['01-25', 'name1@company.com']), 'name2': set(['name2@company.com', '11-29']), 'name3': set(['08-15', 'name3@company.com']), 'name4': set(['01-24', 'name4@company.com'])}
```

My questions is how do I access the email. I understood the hard way that the values in my dictionary are currently a ‘set’ that I can’t access by indexing. Once I do print `dict[name][1]` then I get the error TypeError:

> 'set' object does not support indexing

Comment: *Why* have you used a set? That doesn't seem to be a good use case for a set.

Comment: Why don't you use a list simply?

Comment: Well, that info in the dictionary are being imported form an xlsx file and each name,bday,email in coming form a column in that xlsx sheet. see below:  for i in range(1,6):
    name = str(col0[i].value)[0:]
    emails = str(col2[i].value)[0:]
    bdays = str(col1[i].value)[5:10]
    dict.setdefault(name , {emails,bdays})

Comment: You should put that as an edit in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sets are unordered data structures, so you cannot access them with the index.
Even if you typecast them to a list, and then use a index,i.e. `list(dict[name])[1]` it is not guaranteed to return correct element, as the order of the list is not defined.

Your way to pick out matching element can be to iterate the set, and select the element which matches conditions like `type` and any possible regex, but that is also prone to error, unless your sets have few elements of different types.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a set when you create the dict, where you should be using a list or a tuple.

```
dict.setdefault(name, [emails,bdays])
```

Comment: That's it.........Thanks.  a list in a dictionary is easier than a dictionary in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
date = today.strftime('%m-%d')
for names in var.keys():
    if date in var[names]: 
        for x in var[names]:
            if x != date:
                email = x
                print  "Found a bday for " + email
```

But there are better options to store this information.